# VBA *Wildcard* Vlookup - or alternative

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard, vlookup

I am looking to write a bit of code using the Vlookup function to return a value to an adjacent column. However i would like the lookup to work with a wildcard ie not require an exact match.

The code below will look down column D row by row, then use the value to lookup the corresponding value from the data table and return it to column E. This sort of works but cant cope well with missing or incorrect values.

The data in column D will be full text format sentences so i just need to look for key words and then return a set reference value for data processing.

```
    Sub LookUpComments() 'exact match only ???

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim DataRow As Long
    Dim DataClm As Long
    Dim Result As Variant

DataTable = Sheet3.Range("D5:D35")
LookUpTable = Sheet3.Range("AA10:AB20")
Sheet3.Range("E5:E10000").ClearContents

DataRow = Sheet3.Range("E5").Row
DataClm = Sheet3.Range("E5").Column

For Each cl In DataTable

        If cl = "" Then GoTo E
        Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, LookUpTable, 2, blnLookupType)
        If Result = Error Then GoTo E
        Sheet3.Cells(DataRow, DataClm) = Result

E:            DataRow = DataRow + 1
Next cl

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Data LookUp is complete"

End Sub
```

I hope I have made that clear enough? If this function is not possible, do you think i could use some kind of looping find and replace function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Vlookup like you're doing with blnLookupType set to true doesn't give the result you want, you can use Range.Find, then return the value you want with Offset. It supports wildcards and you can search for either part of a string or a whole. See examples below.

```
Sub FindingPart()

Dim rng As Range, found As Range
Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A:A")

Set found = rng.Find(What:="as", LookAt:=xlPart) 'Will find for example "bass"
If Not found Is Nothing Then returnValue = found.Offset(0, 1)

End Sub



Sub FindingWildCards()

Dim rng As Range, found As Range
Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A:A")

Set found = rng.Find(What:="as*", LookAt:=xlWhole) 'Would find for example "ashes" but not "bass"
If Not found Is Nothing Then returnValue = found.Offset(0, 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the advice, looks like I was going down the wrong path with just VLookup.

I have now wriiten a code which functions perfectly for what I need, although I'm sure it can be written much better. I used a vlookup to obtain a return value for each search criteria then looped a find/replace for each one.

```
Sub FilterComments()

On Error Resume Next

Dim Rng As Range, found As Range
Dim Rtn As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    LookUpValue = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("LOOKUP").Range("I10:I108")
    LookUpTable = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("LOOKUP").Range("I10:J108")

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IEOutput").Range("W:W").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IEOutput").Range("T:T").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IEOutput").Range("W1").Value = "LOOKUP COMMENT"

Set Rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IEOutput").Range("W:W")

        For Each cl In LookUpValue
        If cl = "" Then GoTo E

            Rtn = Application.VLookup(cl, LookUpTable, 2, False)


            Rng.Replace What:="*" & cl & "*", Replacement:=Rtn, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
E:
        Next cl


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox "Data LookUp is complete", vbInformation, "GM PMS Data Filter"

End Sub
```

Hope this helps anyone else who is trying to do a similar thing